# eclipse 4 application error

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to learn eclipse 4 application development.By following the steps described in this link
[eclipse 4 rcp tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4RCP/article.html) I created a eclipse 4 application, but when I run it, I get these error messages in console:

```
!SESSION 2012-10-03 10:22:00.511 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_31
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=zh_CN
Framework arguments:  -product test.product
Command-line arguments:  -product test.product -data D:\e4rcp_workspace/../runtime-test.product -dev file:D:/e4rcp_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/test.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.552
!MESSAGE Product test.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.579
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.579
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.v20120806-171245.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.579
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.579
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.3.v20120806-170624.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.580
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.580
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.2.v20120802-184737.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.580
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.580
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.10.2.v20120814-175454.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.581
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.581
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.10.2.v20120726-172631.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.581
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.581
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.10.2.v20120821-165957.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.581
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.590
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.590
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.10.2.v20120821-165957 [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.590
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.590
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.591
!MESSAGE Bundle test_1.0.0.qualifier [4] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.591
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.10.2.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.591
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.10.3.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.591
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.2.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.591
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.592
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.10.2.v20120814-175454 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.592
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.592
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.592
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.592
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.592
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.593
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.593
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.2.v20120802-184737 [32] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.593
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.10.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.593
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.593
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.594
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.594
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.594
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.594
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.10.3.v20120822-140642 [33] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.594
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.595
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.10.2.v20120726-172631 [37] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.595
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.595
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.3.v20120806-170624 [52] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.595
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.595
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.596
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.596
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.v20120806-171245 [57] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.596
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.611
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.611
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.v20120806-171245.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.611
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.611
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.3.v20120806-170624.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.612
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.612
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.2.v20120802-184737.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.612
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.612
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.10.2.v20120814-175454.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.612
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.613
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.10.2.v20120726-172631.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.613
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.613
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.10.2.v20120821-165957.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.613
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.621
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.621
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.10.2.v20120821-165957 [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.621
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.621
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.622
!MESSAGE Bundle test_1.0.0.qualifier [4] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.622
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.10.2.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.622
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.10.3.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.622
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.2.
!SUBENTRY 2 test 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.622
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.622
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.10.2.v20120814-175454 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.623
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.623
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.623
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.623
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.623
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.624
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.624
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.2.v20120802-184737 [32] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.624
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.10.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.624
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.624
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.624
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.625
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.625
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.10.3.v20120822-140642 [33] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.625
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.10.2.v20120726-172631 [37] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.625
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.626
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.3.v20120806-170624 [52] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.626
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.626
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.626
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.626
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.v20120806-171245 [57] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.626
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-03 10:22:01.628
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
An error has occurred. See the log file
D:\e4rcp_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\test.product\1349230920702.log.
```